# Qt Desinger и изменение размеров

Tags: qt, qtcreator, виджет

В моей программе есть три области:

1) Кнопки, поля, чебоксы и тд

2) Виджет

3) Виджет

Я хочу чтобы первая область имела фиксированный размер по горизонтали.

Сейчас я раскидал все элементы первой области в вертикальный layout, потом его и два виджета в горизонтальный. После сделал выравнивание по сетке. Теперь при изменении размеров экрана все эти три части раздвигаются(иногда бывает что раздвигается только первая часть с кнопками, тем самым виджеты по горозонтали вообще не меняют размер), а мне хотелось бы, чтобы область с кнопками не меняла размер по горизонтали при расширении окна, а растягивались только два виджета. Вот что у меня есть сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задайте фиксированные размер элементам(или Layout). Я не помню точно какие свойства нужно установить, но совершенно точно сработает выставление минимального и максимального значения ширины.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У горизонтального лайоута(нромер 6 кажется) задайте значение `layoutStretch` равное `0,1`. Тогда левая половина не будет изменять свои размеры, а правая будет

[image]

[image]

**UPD:** Как это работает.
Меняя свойство `layoutStretch` мы задаем коэффициенты растяжения для каждой ячейки лайоута. Задав значение `0, 1` мы говорим, что при растяжении окна на 1 пиксель, 0 отойдет левой ячейке и 1 правой. К слову, значение `0, 10` или `0, 100` даст точно такой же эффект. Роль играет не абсолютное значение коэффициентов растяжения, а их отношение. Если мы хотим чтобы ячейки растягивались в определенной пропорции, то можем задать значение, например, `3, 7`. Тогда при растягивании окна на 10 пикселей, 3 уйдут влево, а 7 вправо.

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало! А как теперь такое можно сделать, чтобы фиксированный размер был справа? Равносильно тому что у вертикального layouta фиксированный размер был внизу.

Comment: @NightBlue3, обновил ответ